# Google Places Auto Complete fragment causes duplicate id error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

Hi I am using google's places autocomplete api in my app. I need the google places fragment in another fragment and have got it working. Basically I have a tab with 3 imagviews and when you click on one a fragment would fill the main frame layout. Initially if I click on the imagview that brings up the fragment with the autocomplete places fragment, it works. However if I go on to another tab and then back to it I get a duplicate id error on the google places autocomplete fragment.

This is the xml of the fragment that contains the autocomplete fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
        tools:layout="@layout/place_autocomplete_fragment" />
```

And this is the code in the fragment that holds the autocomplete fragment:

```
this.locationSearchBar = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
```

This is the error I get :

```
Duplicate id 0x7f0800dc, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0800f6 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment
```

I read the other similar questions but none of their solutions worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried simply changing the fragment id? or the error appears with every id you use? Because you have a layout with the same name referenced with `tools:layout=@layout/place_autocomplete_fragment`

Comment: You're trying to find the Activity's Fragment... Not from the current  Fragment

Comment: I get it with every id

Comment: @Mat `tools:` attributes are removed at compile time

Comment: @cricket_007 the error appears when im inflating the fragment layout for the second time. Its as though the autocomplete fragment is never destroyed even when the fragment it is in is.

Comment: The documentation says to embed in an Activity, or start an Intent. Doesn't mention embed within a Fragment. https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

Comment: @cricket_007 is there a way to add it to the fragment dynamically instead of specifying it in the xml file?

Comment: Sure. A FragmentTransaction with a FrameLayout works. I still don't know why you want to nest a Fragment within another

Comment: I don’t but I need the placesautocomplete fragment inside a fragment.

Comment: Is there no way to have the google placesautocomplete inside a fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this code:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mAutocompleteFragment != null && getActivity() != null && !getActivity().isFinishing()) {
        getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mAutocompleteFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

You could also put this in onDestroyView() I believe. The AutocompleteFragment will need to be removed from each ACTIVITY before it is added to the same Activity. This was an issue for me when I created and later destroyed a Fragment with an AutocompleteFragment added to it and then tried to create the same Fragment again without having destroyed the Activity that it runs within.

Comment: Thanks worked for me but I need to  call this onDestroyView(); Thanks man